# polynomial with complex roots

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

[image]

As I understans - this polynomial has 4 different roots. We are given $z_1=3-2i$, so $z_2=3+2i$. So we already have 2 of 4 roots. I expressed the polynomial as $(x^2+2)(x^2-6x+13)$. I solved each of these equations separately and got $x_{1,2}=\pm i$ for $(x^2+2)$ and $x_{3,4}=\pm 2i$ for $(x^2-6x+13)$

So there are 6 roots in total. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you solve the two equations? (Hint: you solved both of them incorrectly. But you did OK up to that point.)

Comment: If I tell you that $1$ is a root of the polynomial $x - 1$, how many roots does $x - 1$ have? You are double-counting the given roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miscalculating the roots of the polynomial.

Indeed, since $3 - 2i$ is a root and the coefficients of $p(z)$ are real, $3 + 2i$ is also a root.

Taking advantage of such fact, we can conclude that $z^{2} - 6z + 13$ is a factor of $p(z)$.

Hence we have that
\begin{align*}
z^{4} - 6z^{3} + 15z^{2} - 12z + 26 & = (z^{4} - 6z^{3} + 13z^{2}) + (2z^{2} - 12z + 26)\\\\
& = z^{2}(z^{2} - 6z + 13) + 2(z^{2} - 6z + 13)\\\\
& = (z^{2} + 2)(z^{2} - 6z + 13)
\end{align*}
whence it results the other roots are given by $\pm i\sqrt{2}$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that the $2i$ roots cannot solve the second quadratic, since this gives you $(x-2i)(x+2i)=x^2+4$, not $x^2-6x+13$.

You know this without even solving it, because you only obtained that quadratic by multiplying the two roots you already had!

Then the complete solution set is the given root, its conjugate, and the solutions of $x^2+2=0$ which are $\pm \sqrt{-2}=\pm i\sqrt{2}$.